# Debian, node installation, release file error

Tags: node.js, docker, debian

I have a question regarding Debian and node installation.

On this line in my Dockerfile: `RUN   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs`, building a docker fails with the following error:

```
Step 13/21 : RUN   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in ef7d9114d16f

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Get:2 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Err:2 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device)
Ign:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Ign:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release [89.4 kB]
Err:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device)
Err:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Error executing command, exiting
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The build works on another person’s machine and works fine when it’s deployed to staging. 
Do you have any ideas about how this can be fixed?

Comment: please share your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

The relevant issue was the `Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device)`.

I run `docker system prune`, reclaimed 32GB and it run fine.